# Why doesn't the delay of an FIR filter equal the number of taps but half of them?

Tags: finite-impulse-response

I have seen the mathematical proofs that show that the delay of an FIR filter is half the filter order, i.e N/2. Yet I am still confused:

When I look in the time domain, the output of the filter is: 
\begin{align}
 y[n] &= b_0 x[n] + b_1 x[n-1] + \cdots + b_N x[n-N] \\
      &= \sum_{i=0}^{N} b_i\cdot x[n-i],
\end{align}
where N  is the filter order. 
So clearly the output at a given index n depends on the input of N preceding input values, so why is the delay N/2 ?

Comment: Peter was right to mark this as duplicate. You're not paying attention to the wording: Half the filter order is the **group** delay, and not that of just *any* FIR filter, but that of **linear phase filters** only. The exact things that you make statements about make a difference, so be a bit more careful when talking about specific things. In a mathematical context like this, qualifiers such as "group" or "linear phase" are almost never used in vain; they are essential to the meaning of the words.

Comment: Let me be more specific: